# Linux nohup command not working correctly

Tags: python, linux, process, nohup

So I have a startup script that's suppose to run this python script in the background using nohup. And I use nohup because I don't want it to be dependent on if I'm logged in or not. So, it's running from an SD card which I then turned into an image and burned onto another card.

The strange thing is that it works correctly in the first and not the second. I can look at nohub.out in the first and see the expected output but in the copy it's completely blank.

When I do ps aux | grep python I can see the script process running in both so I'm not sure why the copy doesn't seem to be doing what it's suppose to

Comment: Are you using a `*nix` based filesystem on the new SD Card as well ? And also it would be good to tell us how you created the image and transferred it to the second SD card ? There could be some inconsistencies because of the way you transferred too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently they all had to be set to lock for some reason. When I did that they worked as expected

Answer (score 2):

Without the full context, it's hard to guess, but the difference may stem simply from the fact that one of the SD-card is write protected - or mounted read-only. If that isn't the case, can you please post the output of

```
mount
```

with both cards ?

You may wish to use `screen` instead of `nohup`: start

```
screen
```

Then run the program normally, and then detach by pressing Ctrl+A then D. Regain control of the terminal later (even after logging off) with

```
screen -r
```

Comment: I know it isn't write protected because I've been editing the script with different suggestions (although none have worked). I'll try screen but I'm assuming that stops when the device the card is in powers off...

Comment: In terms of the full context the SD card is in a raspberry pi and its just suppose to be running the python script in the background once the device is powered on

Comment: To me, `screen` is a better `nohup` (although admittedly `nohup` makes it easier to have the full log, but in that case you may juste pipe the output to `tee`).  But that doesn't stop the program from dying if the computer is switched off...

If you want a script that always run, you have to provide a startup script for it in `/etc/init.d` (or whatever directory your distro uses) and have a startup link for it in the appropriate `/etc/rc.?d`, or just add it in `/etc/rc.local`.